# Make text box respond to treeview selection

Tags: c#, treeview

In this project there are multiple reports being generated.  Each report can have unlimited subreports, making this a completely recursive solution.  I need to make a C# viewer to show these reports, so I made a basic prototype at the moment with a left panel of a treeview and the right panel with a textbox.

My problem is I cannot figure out a way to have the right text populate with the information from the left report (from the tree view) properly.  The names of the reports can be duplicates.  I was originally adding all of the information to a dictionary with the report names for the keys and the data as the values, but this was not working because of the duplicate titles...

I wanted to use some kind of unique random ID for each report to associate the treenodes with the correct report information, but I seem to be having difficulty doing this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx

From what I have read it doesn't seem like there is some kind of property I can use to do this...How can I make the right textbox populate the information from the report based on the selected treenode on the left side?  The treenodes are being added recursively at the moment, and like I said there can be duplicates, so the names of the nodes are not necessarily unique.

Thanks, I will be happy to answer any further questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `TreeNode.Tag` property to store a reference to the report:

```
TreeNode node = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(report.Name);
node.Tag = report;
```

Then, in the `AfterSelect` event handler, retrieve the report from the `Tag` property of the selected node:

```
Report report = (Report)e.Node.Tag;
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much, I spent an hour trying to figure this out, and it was literally two lines of code *facepalm*